# Bokeh Sliders associated with a plot (without bokeh server)

Tags: python, bokeh

I'm trying to plot my 1D PDE in time using bokeh. I have a nparray U where each line is a time slice( dt ) and each column is a space slice (dx), therefore U[0] is my initial condition and U[n] is my n-th iteration.

Of course if I ask to plot(x,U[t]) for every t, I get the correct plot (as good as my approximations can be ;-), but I would like associate this with a time slider for interactivity (of course in future I would like to "play" it as animation ;-)

For now I would like to avoid to use bokeh server, since I want that this HTML be an stand alone "application"

The issue here is that callbacks just don't work, or at least I'm not being able to update the graph. I don't want to run a "bokeh" server since all my data is already inside a numpy data structure (U array). Every line is a iteration in time and every column is a dx.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

from   __future__ import division
from   bokeh.models import ColumnDataSource, HBox, VBoxForm, HoverTool
from   bokeh.models.widgets import Slider, TextInput
from   bokeh.plotting import Figure, output_file, show
import numpy as np

def linearconv(nx,c=1,sigma=0.5,tmax=1,xmax=3):

    nt=int((tmax/xmax)*((nx-1)/(c*sigma))+1)    # Time Grid

    x,dx=np.linspace(0,xmax,nx,retstep=True)
    t,dt=np.linspace(0,tmax,nt,retstep=True)


    # Initial conditions
    #
    # u=2 if 0.5 <= x <= 1
    # u=1 everywhere else in the support
    U = np.ones((nt,nx))
    U[0][np.where((.5<=x) & (x<=1))]=2

    # Calculate the wave over the time
    for n in range(1,nt):
        for i in range(1,nx):
            U[n][i]= U[n-1][i] - c*dt/dx* ( U[n-1][i]-U[n-1][i-1] )

    return U,x,t,dx,dt,nt

def prepareplot(height=400, width=400,title="Wave @"):
    plot = Figure(plot_height=height, plot_width=width, title=title,
                  tools="crosshair,pan,reset,resize,save,wheel_zoom")

    return plot

def update_ttime(attrname, old, new):
    plot.title = "Wave @{}s".format(title.value)

def update_graph(attrname, old, new):
    # Get the current slider values
    t = time.value

    source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, t=U[t]))
    plot.line('x','t', source=source)
    plot.line('x','t', source=source)


nx=101

# Set up data
U,x,t,dx,dt,nt = linearconv(nx)

plot = prepareplot()

time = Slider(title="Time", value=t[-1], start=t[0], end=t[-1], step=dt)
ttime = TextInput(title="Time", value="{}".format(t[-1]))
source = ColumnDataSource(data=dict(x=x, t=U[-1]))

plot.line('x','t', source=source)


# Set up callbacks
ttime.on_change('value', update_ttime)
time.on_change('value', update_graph)

# Setup layouts
inputs = VBoxForm(children=[ttime,time])
layout = HBox(children=[inputs,plot], width=800)

# Plot the plot
output_file("sli.html")
show(layout)
```

Comment: Callbacks that execute real python code (i.e., using `.on_change`) can *only* work with a Bokeh server. The reason is simple, your browser has no way to run python code. Running python code in response to UI events is the main reason the Bokeh server exists, in fact. It is still possible have highly interactive "standalone" documents using `CustomJS` callbacks, see the User's Guide section on [Adding Interactions](http://bokeh.pydata.org/en/latest/docs/user_guide/interaction.html#javascript-callbacks) Of course, for an approach like this you have to send *all* the data up front to the browser